# Materialize.css - How to disable ripple effect/ waves effect on a specified element (anchor tag)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I'm trying to remove the ripple effect/ waves effect only from a specified anchor tag but unable to achieve it. Any ideas?

Anchor tag:

```
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       <span>My Policies</span>
       <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
```

The class "waves-effect waves-light" gets added dynamically like this:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span>My Policies</span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` method of `jQuery` to add or remove class from elements.

In your case you want to add **Ripple Effect** to an anchor tag. So assign an id to that anchor tag and use `.addClass()` method to add or `.removeClass()` to remove the **Ripple Effect**.

So you can trigger an event like `button click, page load` to add/remove your class (`waves-effect waves-light`)

> I have created a **jsfiddle** take a look:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/s52ko6eo/

***Example:***

**HTML**

```
<a class="blue nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

    <span>My Policies</span>

    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>

</a>

<br><button id="btn" class="btn">Add Ripple</button>

<br><br><button id="btn2" class="btn">Remove Ripple</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Adds `waves-effect wave-light` class to `anchor`
    $('#btn').click(function(){

        $('#navbarDropdownMenuLink3').addClass('waves-effect waves-light');
    });


    // Removes `waves-effect wave-light` class from `anchor`
    $('#btn2').click(function(){

        $('#navbarDropdownMenuLink3').removeClass('waves-effect waves-light');

    });

});
```